# Evaluation of python expression

Tags: python, lambda, boolean-logic, evaluation, expression-evaluation

I came across the below expression in python to evaluate if a number is odd or even. While it looks elegant I was surprised to see it work. I guess for the input `3`:
`x%2` equals `1` which evaluates to `True` and non-empty strings (`odd`) evaulate to `True`. So we have `True and True or <don't have to check because it doesn't matter if True or False as the overall statement will be True>`. But why is the output in that case not `True` but `odd` - what concept do I miss?

```
>>> (lambda x:
... (x % 2 and 'odd' or 'even'))(3)
'odd'
```

Comment: `True and "odd"` evaluates to `"odd"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `and` and `or` operators are not limited to True and False; they return one of their operands.

```
>>> 1 and "odd"
'odd'
>>> 0 or "even"
'even'
```